# Is $\mathcal{C}^\infty([0,1])$ normable?

Tags: functional-analysis

The space $\mathcal{C}^\infty(]0,1[)$ of smooth real functions over $]0,1[$ is not normable (because it is infinite dimensional and Montel).

Consider instead the space $\mathcal{C}^\infty([0,1])$ of smooth real functions over $[0,1]$. [Here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_de_Fr%C3%A9chet), wiki says it is *not* normable. Is it a typo on wikipedia ? If not, why aren't $\|\cdot\|_2$ or $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norms on $\mathcal{C}^\infty([0,1])$ ?

Comment: Those induce a weaker topology than the standard topology.

Comment: Ok thanks. And what is the standard topology on $\mathcal{C}^\infty([0,1])$ ?

Comment: The topology induced by the family of seminorms $p_n \colon f \mapsto \lVert f^{(n)}\rVert_{\infty}$. It's the topology of uniform convergence of all derivatives. That makes it a Montel space too.

Comment: Ok perfect. Thanks.